# Type III von Neumann algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\mathcal M$ be a type $\mathrm{III}$ von Neumann algebra. Is it true that for all $n\geq 1,$ $\mathcal M$ contains a copy of $M_n$ as a von Neumann subalgebra? By Theorem 9.24 of [these lecture notes](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Eaioana/von%20Neumann%20algebras.pdf), I just need to show that for all $n\in\ N$ there are mutually orthogonal projections $p_1,\dots,p_n$ such that $p_1+\dots+p_n=1.$

Comment: you mean... $M_n$ is a square matrix ring over the field for the algebra?

Comment: Yes! Matrix ring over complex field.

Comment: Any two nontrivial nonidentity projections are equivalent, and so $M $ is isomorphic to $M_n M$, so in particular contains $M_n C $ as a unital subalgebra.